# reactJS application string.replace is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a reactJS application with the following code:

```
dollar_field = formatCurrency(x.substr(12,14));
```

formatCurrency is a function in an external file that I wrote.  the code for formatCurrency looks like this:

```
export function formatCurrency(amt) {

    amt = amt.replace(",","");

    const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
        style: 'currency',
        currency: 'USD',
        minimumFractionDigits: 2
      })

    return formatter.format(result);
};
```

I know the value of x is always going to be a 14 character string of blanks, numeric digits, commas, and a decimal.  In my test case, the value is "      3,123.12".

The problem is I am getting this error:

`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: amt.replace is not a function`

Why would replace not be a valid JavaScript function?

Comment: Are you certain amt is a string?

Comment: When I run this code as described, I get all the way to `result is not defined`. What is the value of `amt` when you get this error? `console.log(amt)` would tell you.

Comment: Make sure the value of "x" is not a number, replace is a String method.

Comment: Clearly, `amt` isn't what you think it is.

Comment: @JakeWorth return formatter.format(result) should be return formatter.format(amt). I just reran the code and its working now.  Its an odd intermittent error when I have .replace. I'll keep working on it.  Thanks.

Comment: @KevinB I added these 2 lines at the top of the function: var str = amt.toString();  amt = str.replace(",",""); This seems to have resolved my issue.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Replace is a String method. So if your function returns the error:

"Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: amt.replace is not a function"

The variable amt is not a string. Are you sure the variable x below is a string

`dollar_field = formatCurrency(x.substr(12,14));`

Also what is result in this function?